# Why is data retrieved from Firestore although giving error that permissions are not sufficient?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am doing a Firestore query in Angular 8 that is displayed directly on a website with `*ngFor`. This data is retrieved from my Firestore collection "IoTData". The strange thing is I have set up a Firestore rule for this collection so that only some users can access the data. *At the same moment* as the data shows up in the browser (after finished loading, since there is quite a lot of data), I also get the error in the console:

> ERROR FirebaseError: "Missing or insufficient permissions."

But why do I get BOTH the error (which I want) and also the data (which I don't want in the case of the current user)? I also get the error for users that should have permissions to view the data.

Extract of my Firestore rules:

```
function getRole(role) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles[role]
}
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /IoTData/{entity} {
        allow get, list: if getRole('admin') == true;
    }
}
```

The query is in the constructor of a class:

```
this.dataCollection = afs.collection<DataItem>('IoTData', ref => ref.where('datetime', '>=', '2020-01-15T09:51:00.000Z').orderBy('datetime','desc'));
    this.data = this.dataCollection.valueChanges();
```

The template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let data_item of data | async">
    <td>{{ data_item.module }}</td>
    <td>{{ data_item.datetime }}</td>
</tr>
```

I also have a button to download the same data that is shown on page, but there I use `.get`. This renders the same error but does not give the data (i.e. everything is as it should be in this case).

Comment: Instead of adding more information in comments, you can edit the question to clarify the issue.